# Check a Label Value in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, if-statement

I am making a shop game from Visual studio c#, and I need to check if a label text is above a price. For example:

```
if (Lbl_Money.Text => 120) {
//EVENT
}
```

I know that this is not really a possible way of doing it, so can anyone help me with a different way of doing this?

Comment: `int.Parse(Lbl_Money.Text) >= 120`?

Comment: All the answers will work, at least for `integer` prices; but you may want to learn about the `Label.Tag` property; here you can store the price as any number type, includig  `decimal` (as anything to do with money __should__ be !!)  and still set the `Label.Text` to anything, maybe including a currency sign etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string to an integer, you can do this,

```
if(int.Parse(Lbl_Money.Text) >= 120)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 int price;
    if( int.TryParse(Lbl_money.Text, out price))
    {
     //Event
    }
```

The int.tryParce function tries to get the number out of the text, if it succeeds it puts it inside the price variable and return true, else, it returns false.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers